# Create SQL Table from a DataStream in a Java/Scala program and query it from SQL Client CLI - Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

Is it possible interact with a table using Flink SQL client CLI where which table was created within a Scala/Java program running in the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.

You could sink the DataStream of the Scala/Java program into a topic in a message queue or event log like Apache Kafka or Apache Pulsar and register the topic as a table in the CLI client.

Once the table is register, it can be queried with SQL in the client.